# change ListBox's particular Item background color at bind time

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox, background-color

I work on c#.net winforms application.
In that i have list box to load some data.so i simple fetch data from database and bind the listbox by same data. For bind the listbox i used this code.

```
 try
        {
            db v = new db();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt = v.retDataTable("select distinct(tableName),tableID from tableMaster  order by tableName ");//retDataTable is function and it return data in datatable.
            listBox1.DataSource = dt;
            listBox1.DisplayMember = "tableName";
            listBox1.ValueMember = "tableID";
        }
        catch (Exception e1)
        {
        }
```

Now my problem:
`I have to check all data which i bind to listbox and change the background color of particular  item as per condition.`
For the what should i do ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are looking for [ListBox.DrawItem Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.drawitem.aspx)

sample code from the MSDN:

```
private void ListBox1_DrawItem(object sender, 
    System.Windows.Forms.DrawItemEventArgs e)
{
    // Draw the background of the ListBox control for each item.
    e.DrawBackground();
    // Define the default color of the brush as black.
    Brush myBrush = Brushes.Black;

    // Determine the color of the brush to draw each item based  
    // on the index of the item to draw. 
    switch (e.Index)
    {
        case 0:
            myBrush = Brushes.Red;
            break;
        case 1:
            myBrush = Brushes.Orange;
            break;
        case 2:
            myBrush = Brushes.Purple;
            break;
    }

    // Draw the current item text based on the current Font  
    // and the custom brush settings.
    e.Graphics.DrawString(ListBox1.Items[e.Index].ToString(), 
        e.Font, myBrush, e.Bounds, StringFormat.GenericDefault);
    // If the ListBox has focus, draw a focus rectangle around the selected item.
    e.DrawFocusRectangle();
}
```

since you have datatable as datasource you need to find the current datarow

```
DataRowView drv = (DataRowView)this.listBox1.Items[e.Index];

var tableID = drv["tableID"].ToString();
var tableName =drv["tableName "].ToString();
```

depend on datatype of the `tableID` you can cast it relevant type and write the condition to change the background color.

And also you need to draw the `tableName` by using `DrawString` method

```
e.Graphics.DrawString(tableName , 
            e.Font, myBrush, e.Bounds, StringFormat.GenericDefault);
```

Comment: i try it and i got color but it have generate one new problem listbox display me data like 'system.Data.datarow'.

Comment: @Archit you can't directly use the sample code for your case.

Comment: @Archit Did you Change DrawMode of List box?

Comment: yes yes i know i can't directly use the sample code. so i change it as per my condition than also i display same think but i got it item value correctly only problem to display dataitem in listbox.

Comment: @saeed yes sure i will  but please tell me which code snippet you want to see ?